# Applying Green's theorem to this integral

Tags: analysis, vector-analysis, line-integrals, greens-theorem

Let the area outside the ellipse $\frac{x^2}{9}+\frac{y^2}{4}=1$ bounded by the curves $\frac{x^2}{25}+\frac{y^2}{16}=1(y\leq 0)$,$x+y=5$ and $y-x=5$ be $R$, $C$ is the outer bound of $R$ and $C_1$ be the inner bound (the ellipse $\frac{x^2}{9}+\frac{y^2}{4}=1$) apply Green's theorem to the integral $$\oint_C\frac{-y}{4x^2+9y^2}dx+\frac{x}{4x^2+9y^2}dy$$.

Now what I am getting is zero as the integrand is equal to the grad of some function f and the integral is over a closed curve, the problem is this question is going to be on the exam and my answer is too obvious to be true, I feel like there is a twist or a trick in there and the answer is not supposed to be 0.

Comment: How do you know it is the grad of some function $f$ ?

Comment: I don't know, it is a simple region and if $\frac{\partial Q}{\partial x}=\frac{\partial P}{\partial y}$ , and I thought I can figure out $f$ but when I tried, it got really complicated as one of the steps requires the integral of the function $\arctan (\frac{1}{y})$ so...

Comment: D[-y/(4 x ^2 + 9 y ^2), y] - D[x/(4 x ^2 + 9 y ^2), x] // Simplify

Comment: It is not a simple region: it is not simply connected nor contractible: the outer ellipse and the straight lines form a simple domain but the smaller ellipse is a hole in this domain. One cannot apply [Poincaré lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poincar%C3%A9_lemma) in this domain. Draw the domain to see it. Many programs can draw the domain, such as [ZeGrapher](https://zegrapher.com/en/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is the singularity at the origin, which ends up making it so that the function is *not* the gradient of some function. You can even try finding such a function, and see that you can't (however you can *locally*, but this is not sufficient). What we can do, however, is observe that

$$I=\oint_C\left(\frac{-y}{4x^2+9y^2}~\mathrm{d}x+\frac{x}{4x^2+9y^2}~\mathrm{d}y\right)=\iint_R\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\frac{x}{4x^2+9y^2}-\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\frac{-y}{4x^2+9y^2}\right)~\mathrm{d}x~\mathrm{d}y-\oint_{C_1}\left(\frac{-y}{4x^2+9y^2}~\mathrm{d}x+\frac{x}{4x^2+9y^2}~\mathrm{d}y\right)$$

by using Green's theorem. But notice that

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\frac{x}{4x^2+9y^2}=\frac{-4x^2+9y^2}{(4x^2+9y^2)^2},$$

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\frac{-y}{4x^2+9y^2}=\frac{-4x^2+9y^2}{(4x^2+9y^2)^2},$$

and so the double integral in the above vanishes, leaving us with

$$I=-\oint_{C_1}\left(\frac{-y}{4x^2+9y^2}~\mathrm{d}x+\frac{x}{4x^2+9y^2}~\mathrm{d}y\right).$$

But this is especially nice due to how $C_1$ is defined. In particular, we can parameterize it by the function $\gamma:[0,2\pi)\to C_1$ defined by

$$\gamma(\theta)=(3\cos\theta,2\sin\theta),$$

which has derivative given by

$$\gamma'(\theta)=(-3\sin\theta,2\cos\theta).$$

Applying the definition of the line integral we thus get that

$$I=-\int_0^{2\pi}\left(\frac{-2\sin\theta}{4(3\cos\theta)^2+9(2\sin\theta)^2}(-3\sin\theta)+\frac{3\cos\theta}{4(3\cos\theta)^2+9(2\sin\theta)^2}2\cos\theta\right)~\mathrm{d}\theta=-\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{6(\cos^2\theta+\sin^2\theta)}{9(\cos^2\theta+\sin^2\theta)}~\mathrm{d}\theta=-\frac{2}{3}\int_0^{2\pi}\mathrm{d}\theta=-\frac{4\pi}{3}.$$

Comment: I knew it, thank you very much I bothered you with my problems

Answer (score -1):

```
   0 ==D[-y/(4 x ^2 + 9 y ^2), y] - D[x/(4 x ^2 + 9 y ^2), x] // Simplify
```

So your function is indeed a gradient locally for

```
   {x,y}!=0.
```

But the two partial integrals seem to be different

```
{ Integrate[-y/(4 x ^2 + 9y ^2),x] ,Integrate[x/(4 x ^2 + 9y ^2),y]}   
-> {-(1/6) ArcTan[(2 x)/(3 y)],1/6 ArcTan[(3 y)/(2 x)]}.
```

Introduce polar coordinates. The differentials are r-independent by inspection. The the arc integral is a constant.

```
     (-y dx + x dy)/(4 x^2 + 9 y^2)/.
        {x->r Cos[\[Phi]], y -> r Sin[\[Phi]],
         dx-> dr Cos[\[Phi]]- r Sin[\[Phi]] d\[Phi],
         dy -> dr Sin[\[Phi]]+ r Cos[\[Phi]] d\[Phi] }//FullSimplify


       Integrate[2  /(-13+5 Cos[2 \[Phi]]),{\[Phi],0,2\[Pi]}]

       -(Pi/3)
```